# What does "wagon" mean in argot?

Tags: sens, traduction, vocabulaire, argot, littérature

Céline writes a dialogue in *Guignol's Band* : " - Merde ! Eh, Chinois ! Tu nous les casses ! Au vent ta morue ! **Wagon** !"

I looked it up in the dictionary but couldn't find a popular meaning for the word **wagon**, and I believe the literal connotation doesn't fit the context.

Then I found the English translation of this sentence, in which **wagon** is conceived as **slob** : "Shit ! Hey, Chinaman, you're a pain in the arse ! The hell with your bitch ! The slob !"

Does anyone know what **wagon** mean in this context ? Is the translation as **slob** a good one ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Dictionnaire du français non conventionnel* (Jacques Cellard et Alain Rey, 1980) dates the first use of the word *wagon* as meaning  ***prostituée*** to 1864.
« L'emploi métaphorique est amené par l'idée du "transport en commun" que chacun peut emprunter à prix fixe (le wagon, la prostituée), et dans lequel (sur laquelle) se succèdent les "voyageurs". La fin du 19<sup>e</sup> siècle a distingué entre le *wagon de première classe*, prostituée chic, et le *wagon* banal. Vieux. »*

---

<sup>*The metaphoric use is brought about through the idea of public transport in which (on which) individuals can ride provided a fixed price. At the end of 19th c. the use of the word distinguished between *fist class carriage* and plain *carriage*. Outdated.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

There is a slang meaning ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/wagon#:%7E:text=wagon%20va.%C9%A1%C9%94%CC%83%20ou%20%28Belgique%29%20wa.%C9%A1%C9%94%CC%83%20masculin%20%28Chemin%20de,fer%20pour%20transporter%20des%20marchandises%20ou%20des%20voyageurs.)).

> **wagon** (Péjoratif) (Argot) (Rare) Vieille femme usée par la débauche

As the word "morue", which precedes "wagon" is also of the same sort, it is likely that "wagon" has this signification.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/morue#:%7E:text=Morue%20ou%20morlue%20vient%20du%20breton%20mor%20%28mer%29,tandis%20que%20la%20morue%20est%20sal%C3%A9e%20et%20s%C3%A9ch%C3%A9e.)) **morue**  (Vulgaire) (Injurieux) Femme facile, voire prostituée.
> ♦  Dis donc, cette morue va nous casser la cabane ! Neutralise-la, Bon Dieu ! Neutralise la ! — (Michel Audiard, Le cave se rebiffe, 1962)

A translation could be "*slut*" (for both terms).